# setColWidths in R Package openxlsx Throws error

Tags: r, openxlsx

I have some code in R that ran perfectly for me last week.  This week, I am getting the following error:

Error in setColWidths(wb, 1, cols = 1:6, widths = "auto", hidden = rep(FALSE,  :
object 'cols' not found

This occurs during my first call of setColWidths.  My second call gives this error:

Error in setColWidths(wb, 1, cols = c(7), widths = "auto", hidden = rep(TRUE,  :
object 'cols' not found

There are no data inputs -- just run it, and it should produce a spreadsheet.  Did something break?  I have re-installed OpenXLSX.

```
library(openxlsx)

cat("\f")

wb<-createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, "Client Input Form")
writeData(wb, 1, "What Is Your Name?", xy=c(1,1))
writeData(wb, 1, "What Is Your Favorite Color?", xy=c(2,1))
writeData(wb, 1, "What Is Your Quest?", xy=c(3,1))
writeData(wb, 1, "What Is The Capital of Assyria?", xy=c(4,1))

writeData(wb, 1, "Alex", xy=c(1,2))
writeData(wb, 1, "Lee", xy=c(1,3))
writeData(wb, 1, "Maya", xy=c(1,4))

writeData(wb, 1, "Red", xy=c(7,1))
writeData(wb, 1, "Yellow", xy=c(7,2))
writeData(wb, 1, "Blue", xy=c(7,3))

dataValidation(wb, 1, col = 2, rows = 2:4, type = "list", value ="$G$1:$G$3")
setColWidths(wb, 1, cols=1:6, widths = "auto", hidden = rep(FALSE, length(cols)), ignoreMergedCells = FALSE)
setColWidths(wb, 1, cols=c(7), widths = "auto", hidden = rep(TRUE, length(cols)), ignoreMergedCells = FALSE)

unprotect<-createStyle(locked = FALSE)
addStyle(wb, sheet=1, unprotect, rows=2:4, cols=2:4, gridExpand = TRUE)
protectWorksheet(wb, 1, protect = TRUE, lockFormattingCells = FALSE, lockFormattingColumns = TRUE, lockInsertingColumns = TRUE, lockDeletingColumns = TRUE, password="somepw")

saveWorkbook(wb, file = file.choose(), overwrite = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setColWidths(wb, 1, cols=1:6, widths = "auto", hidden = rep(FALSE,
length(cols)), ignoreMergedCells = FALSE) 
setColWidths(wb, 1,
cols=c(7), widths = "auto", hidden = rep(TRUE, length(cols)),
ignoreMergedCells = FALSE)
```

Should be:

```
setColWidths(wb, 1, cols=1:6, widths = "auto", hidden = rep(FALSE, length(1:6)), ignoreMergedCells = FALSE)
setColWidths(wb, 1, cols=c(7), widths = "auto", hidden = rep(TRUE, length(7)), ignoreMergedCells = FALSE)
```